# How can I manipulate properties in a running .NET application?

Tags: .net, winforms

Windows Live Writer's editing surface wraps the IE Browser Control. The WindowsLive.Writer.BrowserControl class has a TextSize property which probably sets the zoom for the editing surface, but there's no UI to set the property. I've messed with stuff like this before using Snoop (WPF), Spy++ (general Windows), etc., but it's been a while. If I wanted to write a console application which found the Windows Live Writer instance and changed the BrowserControl's TextSize property, how would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

You could maybe use the Microsoft UI-Automation to manipulate any type of control in any Windows-Application (MFC, WinForms and WPF).
Have a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163288.aspx

Comment: I messed with that a bit, but it didn't seem like it would allow setting specific control properties like that. Maybe I missed something.

Comment: To be usable in the UI Automation, the specific property has to be  exposed in the AutomationPeer(done by Microsoft or you if it would be your control). Maybe this one isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Hawkeye](http://hawkeye.codeplex.com/). It can inspect and edit any object from a .Net application, including changing properties of controls within the application.

If just using the tool is not good enough, you could look at how it achieves the behaviour in its source code (its on CodePlex) and use a similar mechanism.